# Reading and writing data to SD card in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading and Writing a file from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019783/reading-and-writing-a-file-from-sd-card)

I am a part of a group project where we have to develop our own Android app in Eclipse.
My part of the project requires that I be able to read and write data to the SD card.  I have been able to successfully read and write to files on the internal storage, but I'm having a hard time being able to do it to the SD card.
All of the websites I've looked at have not been very useful.  I am brand new to Eclipse so I don't understand much about it.

I was wondering if I could get step by step instructions on how to get some kind of stream setup to the SD card. All I have to do is simply store text to files.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019783/reading-and-writing-a-file-from-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

do you used permissions elements in manifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way to write the txt file to SD card, reading file from SD card is very similar,

```
File getExternalDir(String dirName) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    return dir;
}


void saveFile(){

File txtFile = new File(getExternalDir(cacheDirectory), fileName);

// write the txt file to SD card
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(txtFile, true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

writer.write(result.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
}
```